# How do I prevent values being shown as # in excel

Tags: excel

I have a cell which is formatted as Text field with wrap text on. The values are shown as "#" when I move away from the cell, how do I prevent it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try to expand the column size (width). If this doesn't help try to format the cell as General instead of Text.

When this happens to me I just have to expand the column size so that the content fits perfectly within the cell.

More about it here:

[Excel - #### sign in cell formatted "Wrap Text"](http://en.allexperts.com/q/Excel-1059/sign-cell-formatted-Wrap.htm)